# JQuery autocomplete cannot get data remotely

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to make autocomplete work with data retrieven remotely from a php script.

If I pass an array arrx directly to the source it works fine.

```
arrx = [{id:'48',label:'TEST 1'},{id:'49',label:'TEST 2'},{id:'50',label:'TEST 3'},{id:'51',label:'TEST 4'}]


                        $("#search2").autocomplete({
                            source: arrx,
                            minLength: 0,
                            select: function(event, ui) {
                                var url = ui.item.id;

                                   alert(url);

                            }
                        }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                        return $( "<li></li>" )
                            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                            .append( "<a>" + item.label  + " " + item.value + "</a>" )
                            .appendTo( ul );
                            } ;
```

but if the same array is returned with a php page

source: '/myfolder/search.php'

nothing shows up. I have searched the problem but cannot find a solution.

Could you give me some help?

**EDIT:** 
with firebug I see that the data is retrieven correctly every time I input a character. Still nothing shows up

**/myfolder/search.php** returns

```
[{id:'48',label:'TEST 1'},{id:'49',label:'TEST 2'},{id:'50',label:'TEST 3'},{id:'51',label:'TEST 4'}]
```

Comment: how u get array from search.php? Is that like same format which is in arrx?

Comment: Yes #Dev, it is the same format.I copy the search.php result into arrx

Comment: can u edit question by editing that array, which you get?

Comment: I am not sure for this,but It might be issue with dom ready mode. when u load page, it only takes values of arrx of that time, then after it will take value only after refreshing page. I think you have to use .live() for a live value. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: #Dev if you're interested I've found that I missed header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); on top of my php page

Answer (score 0):

You should use converte your php array to json array at your remote file using php json encode.

Answer (score 0):

I missed header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

on top of my php page.